# Swift time between run function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I am nearly new to swift Xcode and I am building an app, when the end user is near a iBeacon hi will get a local push notification.
The problem I have is each time he comes near to it(if he got back and forward he will get each time he is near).
So I think to limit by time like 5 minuets of some like that.
I can not find in Swift how to limit a function to run in a time limit.(like 5 minutes)
Can some one point me in the  correct direction?
Thanks for the help.
I did try to work with a timer but it did not do the job for me.

Comment: Post the code that you have tried.

Comment: What about creating a date variable using NSDate to capture the current date and time and testing this variable before running the function?

Answer (score 0):

You Can create a Variable: beaconsHasBeenRecognized to turn to true when the beacon has been recognized, then the next time user goes back and forth, before triggering notification, your code should evaluate it beaconsHasBeenRecognized,its false, otherwise, if it is true, it will not trigger the notification.
Then with the timer, at the moment you set beaconsHasBeenRecognized to true, you start a timer to change beaconsHasBeenRecognized to false within the time that you want, like the 5 minutes.